# Why wont animation repeat on mouseout and mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a box to display an image is hovered over then disapear when the user hovers away from the the displayed box. to achieve this i am using jquery to clone the object but after a successful animation and replace the old animation with a new one but this is not working i have been looking up solutions but i cant find a fix

i have already tried removing the animation classes but it is still not working

**html**

```
<div class="hover-box">
</div>

<div class="row">

<a href="#"><img src="Resources/Images/pic.jpg" class=" img1" /></a>

</div>
```

**css**

```
.hover-box{

    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;

} 

.hover-box.animated{

    display: block;

}
```

**jquery**

```
var box =$('.hover-box').clone(true);

$('.img1').hover(function(){

    $('.hover-box').addClass('animated fadeIn ');

});



 $('.hover-box').mouseout(function(){
    $('.hover-box').addClass('animated fadeOut');
     var el = $(this);
     el.before(box);
     el.replaceWith(box);

});
```

I simply want the box to show on top of the hovered over image then display none when they move the cursor away from the newly hovered box

Comment: Please, add a snippet to test your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you're trying to do, there is no need for clones. jQuery has animation functions `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

**Edit**

Addressed issue of missing handlerOut function for `.hover()` as mentioned.

```js
$('.img1').hover(function() {
  $('.hover-box').fadeIn("slow");
},() => undefined);

$('.hover-box').mouseout(function() {
  $('.hover-box').fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
.hover-box {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hover-box">
</div>

<div class="row">
  <a href="#"><img src="Resources/Images/pic.jpg" class=" img1" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Solved my problem i guess i was trying to rely too much on css when i could have easily solved the issue with jquery

Comment: This runs both `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` animations on `mouseout`. It's not visible, because `fadeOut` runs second but it's technically more expensive than it should be. To not run `fadeIn` you could provide `() => undefined` as the second parameter of `hover()`.

Answer (score 2):

[`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) is not synonym with `mouseenter()`. It is a shorthand for `.mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseout(handlerOut)`, in the form of: `.hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)`.

If `handlerOut` is not provided, it is assumed you want the provided handler run on both in and out state changes.

Therefore, the code you presented does the following:

**handlerIn**:

- add classes `animated fadeIn`

**handlerOut**:

- add classes `animated fadeIn`
- followed by running the code specified in your second binding, on `mouseout`.

You probably want something along these lines:

```
$('.hover-box').hover(
   function() {
     $(this).addClass('hovered');
   },
   function() {
     $(this).removeClass('hovered')
   }
);
```

With the above alone, you can use CSS to tweak how the element animates in and out.

---

Or, to rely on jQuery's animations:

```
$('.hover-box').hover(
  function() {
    $('img', this).fadeIn()
  },
  function() {
    $('img', this).fadeOut()
  }
)
```

Working example:

```js
$('.hover-box').hover(
  function() {
    $('img', this).fadeIn()
  },
  function() {
    $('img', this).fadeOut()
  }
)
```

```css
.hover-box img {
  display: none;
}
.hover-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hover-box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```